# Exception while accessing to distant Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, connection-string

I got an exception

> SYSTEM.DATA.ENTITY.CORE.ENTITYEXCEPTION": The underlined provider
>   failed on open

When my Windows Service try to access to the database
everything used to work fine until today. I tried everything in order to fix it but nothing seemed to work, I'm always having the same exception saying that there was a Timeout and trespassing the Handshake time. But when I created a Console application with the same `App.Config` as the Windows service (Same Prod DB), it worked fine!!!???

Can anybody help me with that because I'm really confused.

Thank's in advance

Comment: You need to provide sample code and more detail on **where** the exception is being thrown.

Comment: you need to add the code to the original post (edit it up and add a code snippet). This will help people answer.